# 'g-recaptcha-response' Is not posted no matter what I try

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

I want to add a simple captcha. And start by testing if the key it's actually posted but I can't get it to post the key.

My form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="<? echo $action; ?>" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="error-container"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><? echo $name; ?></label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" type="text" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><? echo $email; ?></label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-email" name="email" id="email" 
                placeholder="" type="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><? echo $phone; ?></label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-phone" name="phone" id="phone" 
                placeholder="" required>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><? echo $message; ?></label>
        <textarea class="form-control form-control-message" name="message" id="message" placeholder="" rows="10" required></textarea>

    </div>
    <div class="text-left"><br>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mykey" style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"></div>
        <input class="btn active" type="submit" value="Verstuur" /> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

I tried the same with a button or input tag, both didn't post the captcha data.

This simple code shows what I'm trying to do:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) 
{
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

echo $captcha;
echo $name;
}
```

The name is echoed when I submit the form, but $captcha is completely empty.

I got the api loaded before my header ends like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

What more can I try?

Comment: See my answer here it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37733209/5190589