# Submit Button Sends Email even If reCaptcha has been done

Tags: html, forms, submit, recaptcha

Im in the process of adding the reCaptcha from google to my form. The problem is that even though I have followed the instructions from google. I can still press the Submit button without doing the recaptcha. Any Ideas please heres the relevant code snippets.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>webpage title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
```

And the this snippet in the form part of the webpage

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxmyapikeyxxxxxxx_xxxxxxmyapikeyxxxxxxx"></div>  
                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1136056" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>

        </form>
```

As far as I'm aware I have placed the code in the specified areas of my webpage. One before the closing  tag on your HTML template and the snippet at the end of the  where I want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear.

I have put the recaptcha before the submit button. There is a part about the server side integration that I do not understand.

```
[QUOTE]
When your users submit the form where you integrated reCAPTCHA, you'll     
get as part of the payload a string with the name "g-recaptcha-response". 
In order to check whether Google has verified that user, 
send a POST request with these parameters:

URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
secret (required)   xxxxxmysecretkeyxxxxxxx
response (required) The value of 'g-recaptcha-response'.
remoteip    The end user's ip address.
[/QUOTE]
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this please.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we set up the form and make sure your library is included, I prevent the submit button from being clicked while the recaptcha has not been completed and show a tooltip to notify the user it is needed to continue. Then enable it when it has been complete using the callback methods.

**login.php**

```
<div class="formContainer">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <form action="loginHandler.php" method="post" name="login_form" id="loginForm" class="loginForm">  
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p><input type="text" required placeholder="Email" name="email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" required placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password"></p>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="captcha_filled"
                 data-expired-callback="captcha_expired" 
                 data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="show-tt" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Complete the reCAPTCHA to login." data-placement="bottom">
                <input id="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Login">
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    //prevent submit and show tooltip until captch is complete.
    var submit = false;
    $("#submitLogin").prop('disabled', true);

    function captcha_filled() {
        submit = true;
        $("#submitLogin").prop('disabled', false);
        $(".show-tt").tooltip('destroy');
    }
    function captcha_expired() {
        submit = false;
        $("#submitLogin").prop('disabled', true);
        showTooltip();
    }
    function showTooltip () {
        $(".show-tt").tooltip('show');
    }
</script>
```

Now we post to loginHandler.php, or wherever your form submits too and then there we will assign your secret key and then verify the request with google.

**loginHandler.php**

```
$secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secret) .
            '&response=' . urlencode($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) . '&remoteip=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    //ip address is optional
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

    if ($result != null && $result['success'] === true) {

        //success, handle login/submit data or whatever

    } else {
        //response is bad, handle the error
        header('Location: login.php?error=4');
    }
} else {
    //captcha response is not set, handle error
    header('Location: login.php?error=5');
}
```